# warning when fitting variogram - gstat

Tags: r, fitting, variogram

I'm trying to build a variogram model of the semi variance in Zn concentration with distance using gstat package in R.
First I plot the variogram based on my data (it clearly  seems to mean that the model type should be linear according to the plot):

Zn.svar <- variogram(Zn ~ 1, datZn)

plot(Zn.svar)
[image]

Then I try to get a fitted variogram model:

v.fit = fit.variogram(Zn.svar, vgm( "Lin","Sph"))

With 
I get the following warnings that I do not understand:

"Warning messages:
1: In fit.variogram(Zn.svar, vgm("Lin", "Sph")) :singular model in variogram fit

2: In fit.variogram(object, model, fit.sills = fit.sills, fit.ranges = fit.ranges,  :  singular model in variogram fit"

What means the warning "singular model in variagram fit"? can I proceed further to kriging or is there something that went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain why you might be trying to fit a spherical variogram to these data?  The plot suggests it will be ill-defined: you just don't have enough information to determine the sill or the range.

Comment: I know but I was wondering if it was due to the model I used or to something else. I get the same error message when include "Lin"only. When you say "you just don't have enough information..." this is to explain the error message I get?

Comment: It could explain the error message when trying to fit a spherical variogram, but there shouldn't be any problems fitting a linear variogram to these data!  An excellent workaround--to be recommended in any event--is to fit the variogram manually.  Automatic fitting is a good aid for fitting but (IMHO) rarely is a good substitute for the art of variography.

Comment: Could it be that you have more than one row of data for the same coordinates?